# Using an array of callback functions in express in typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, typescript

I'm trying to re-create the [express routing example](http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html) in typescript

I have...

```
/// <reference path='Scripts/typings/express/express.d.ts' />
import express = require('express');
var app = express();

var cb0: express.RequestHandler = function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('CB0');
   next();
}

var cb1: express.RequestHandler = function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('CB1');
    next();
}

var cb2: express.RequestHandler = function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello from C!');
}

var arr: express.RequestHandler[] = [cb0, cb1, cb2];

app.get('/example/c', arr);
```

The first error the typescript compiler throws at me is for `'/example/c'` saying `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RegExp'`... odd, since in `express.d.ts` the function is defined as allowing a string, *or* a regex... but, ok, I change it to `new RegExp('/example/c')`

Then it throws the error `Argument of type 'RequestHandler[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandler'.` at me. Also odd, since the `express.d.ts` file has the method defined as allowing an array.

Very new to typescript here, and these are some cryptic error messages...

Comment: Probably worth noting, the `express.d.ts` came from DefinitelyTyped -https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/express/express.d.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the last line of your snippet to this, and you should be fine:

```
app.get('/example/c', cb0, cb1, cb2);
```

You can't pass in an array of RequestHandlers to that second parameter .... it is a special type of parameter in Typescript called "rest" parameter, analogous to "params" in C#.

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense.